# Does anyone know why this diff amp isn't working?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, differential-amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPCwRO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm new to electronics and I've been figuring out how a diff amp works. I followed a schematic I found on YouTube.

Basically, as V3 increases then VM1 should have a voltage drop, while the opposite should happen on the opposite side.

At least that's what the YouTube video described. But as you can see in this image, it's not working.

What could I be doing wrong?

Here's the link to my reference:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mejPNuPAHBY&t=263s

And here's the image:

[image]

Here's another simulation. As you can the only voltage change that happens is at output VM1
[image]

This is the result of the third simulation.
[image]

Comment: You're connecting 700V to a transistor with pins less than a millimeter apart. This should probably tell you that the device isn't meant for that! That voltage is totally beyond anything reasonable, will instantly make your whole circuit burn in reality. Is V3 maybe supposed to be 0.7V == 700 mV?

Comment: I changed it to 1.1 volts and the readings at the two outputs are equal

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added a new simulation.

Comment: Tip: when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and then click **Save and Insert** an editable schematic link is included in your post. We can then run the simulator and quickly copy and past an editable schematic into our posts. No CircuitLab account is required.

Comment: This definitely isn't going to work very well with either V2 or V3 greater than V1. It'd also work a lot better if you used a current mirror (or current source, but a current mirror is more realistic) instead of R3.

Comment: @RommelBagasina again, 20V is much too high, because is much higher than V1. Maybe you want to start learning how these transistors work before taking a deep dive into difference amplifiers? What you're doing right now is not taking you anywhere.

Comment: @Transistor sadly, I'm using the free version of circuit lab

Comment: @MarcusMüller i get how they work, but regardless if it's too high or too low, I believe the circuit analysis should still apply, which circuitlab does automatically.

Comment: @RommelBagasina It doesn't matter--the circuitlab button in the editor here will allow you to add an editable schematic.

Comment: @Hearth it says i need to save it first, but in order to save it, I need an active membership, which i can't afford.

Comment: @RommelBagasina Are you using the version on this site? EE.SE has an agreement with circuitlab to allow saving on here without needing to have an account.

Comment: @Hearth could I ask what you mean?

Comment: @RommelBagasina When editing your post, there's a button to open circuitlab. It looks like a little circuit diagram, next to the button to add a picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136077/discussion-between-rommel-bagasina-and-hearth).

Comment: @Hearth I already inserted it, could you look at my schematics on what's wrong with it?

Comment: What's wrong with it is that you're using ridiculous values for everything. Do you understand the principles behind why a long-tailed pair works?

Comment: I actually don't, would it be okay to ask you to simulate a working circuit for me? @Hearth

Comment: Apply a little Ohm's Law and you'll see some of your problems. For example, using a 2A current source. Suppose that's divided equally between the two halves of the circuit, 1A per transistor. You have 2000 ohm resistors on the collector of each transistor. Using Ohm's Law, how much voltage do you need to get 1A through 2000 ohms?

Answer (score 3):

With a differential amplifier you usually use a dual polarity power supply. For one using NPN transistors the 'tail' resistor or current source goes to a negative supply, the collector loads go to a positive supply. The alternative for using a single supply is to use a virtual ground.

In a differential amplifier the tail current is usually in the milliamp range, using a 2 A current source is not going to work, not only would the transistors not handle it, but the voltages involved with that much current through the 2000 ohm loads would be in the thousands of volts.

Reduce the tail current to something like 15 mA, and use a dual supply, something like +-15 V. That should give you a good starting point.

Note that the output voltage is the difference of the two collector voltages, V(OUT1) - V(OUT2), where the base of Q2 is the non-inverting input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9CBYS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by assuming that V2 is 5 volts, not 25. Then the current through each transistor is 1 amp. Well, there's a problem to start with - 2N3904s won't handle an amp. But let's let that slide. Since the base currents are equal, so must the collector currents, and that must be 1 amp, since the 2 amp current source will share equally.

And how much voltage will be developed over the collector resistors? Why, 2000 volts, given Ohm's Law. That's quite a trick from a 30 volt supply.

You need to adjust your current source so as to produce something like 15 volts across the collector resistors when the inputs are at your nominal zero level, say about 15 volts. Then you can get a fairly symmetrical swing around that "zero" point.